# Could anyone give suggestion on where to start learning Python?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner, and looking to learn the python language. If you have any suggestions on where I should start it would be nice if you would leave a comment.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I love CodeAcademy gives you a great start and they have an easy to understand tutorial of python.  They have multiple languages you can learn and even provide you with an IDE to type in right in the browser.